# tikzpicture environment rejects or ignores `style` supplied as a `tl` variable.

Tags: tikz-pgf, expl3

Supplying `content` to the `tikzpicture` environment in the form of a `tl` variable works well, but fails for `styles`. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. Sunday 26 November 2017
% BRIEF DESCRIPTION: automating the tikzpicture environment
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g_rn_tikzStyle_FR_tl
\tl_new:N \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl
\cs_new:Npn \rn_buildTikZEnvironment_FR:n #1
%  PARAMETERS:
%    #1: keys presented as a comma separated list of integers.
%  RETURNS: \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl defining content for tikzpicture   environment
  {
\group_begin:
    %%%% lots of code that turns #1 into content and tikzStyle %%%%
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl {\node{12}child{node{6}child
    {node{3}child[missing]child{node{4}}}child{node{10}child{node{7}
    child[missing]child{node{8}}}child{node{11}}}}child{node{17}child
    {node{15}child{node{13}}child{node{16}}}child{node{23}}};}
    \tl_gset:Nx \g_rn_tikzStyle_FR_tl {[level~distance=10mm,
  every~node/.style={circle,draw,inner~sep=1pt},
  level~1/.style={sibling~distance=60mm},
  level~2/.style={sibling~distance=30mm},
  level~3/.style={sibling~distance=15mm},
  level~4/.style={sibling~distance=7.5mm}]}
\group_end:
  }  %  \rn_buildTikZEnvironment_FR:n

\NewDocumentCommand\myShowTree{m}
  {
    \rn_buildTikZEnvironment_FR:n {#1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      %  tikzStyle:
      [level~distance=10mm,
      every~node/.style={circle,draw,inner~sep=1pt},
      level~1/.style={sibling~distance=60mm},
      level~2/.style={sibling~distance=30mm},
      level~3/.style={sibling~distance=15mm},
      level~4/.style={sibling~distance=7.5mm}]      
      %  content:
      \tl_use:N \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand\myShowTreeFinalVersion{m}
  {
    \rn_buildTikZEnvironment_FR:n {#1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      %  tikzStyle:
      \tl_use:N \g_rn_tikzStyle_FR_tl
      %  content:
      \tl_use:N \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
\section{Native tikzpicture: tikzStyle and content both plugged manually into the tikzpicture environment}
The example shows a 13-node height balanced (AVL) tree. The 
tikzpicture environment is composed of two parts, tikzStyle 
and tikZContent. Plugging both into the environment produces 
the tree:

\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=10mm,
every node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1pt},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=60mm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=30mm},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=15mm},
level 4/.style={sibling distance=7.5mm}]
\node{12}child{node{6}child{node{3}child[missing]child{node{4}}}
child{node{10}child{node{7}child[missing]child{node{8}}}child
{node{11}}}}child{node{17}child{node{15}child{node{13}}child
{node{16}}}child{node{23}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\section{tikzStyle supplied manually, tikzContent supplied as an argument}
While the approach taken above may be reasonable for very small content, it is barely 
tolerable for the example 13-node tree. But what if the writer of a tutorial on 
height-balanced trees wishes to demonstrate the effect of deleting a node from a 350 
node AVL tree and then document the sequence of steps required to rebalance the tree? 
No problem, tikzContent can be plugged into the tikzpicture environment as a tl variable. 
Assuming then we have a cs macro that generates tikzContent for trees and returns that 
content as a tl variable, \verb+\myShowTree{m}+ and \verb+\rn_buildTikZEnvironment_FR:n+ 
tell the story. The tikzStyle portion is still plugged into the environment natively, 
but notice that unless spaces are represented as "tilde" characters, compiler ERROR occurs.  

\myShowTree{m}

\section{Both content and tikzStyle supplied as arguments}
Although  the tikzStyle variable \verb+\g_rn_tikzStyle_FR_tl+ returned by 
\verb+\rn_buildTikZEnvironment_FR:n+, when plugged into the tikzpicture environment 
does not result in compilation ERROR, it is ignored. I have gone through the 
standard permutations of expansion control modifiers in my routine headless-chook 
fashion, tried modifying the syntax of the tikzStyles string itself (it is certainly 
sensitive to the presence or absence of the "tilde" character), finally adapted 
"egreg's special" that successfully fixed the format problem for the tabular 
environment, all to no avail. What do I need to to do to get tikzStyles supplied 
as a tl variable to work?

\myShowTreeFinalVersion{m}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just found @egreg 's answer to a question posed by @tobi on Feb 5, 16 which will most likely be the solution to my problem - very similar to what @egreg had proposed recently as answer to a problem I had with the `tabular` environment.

Comment: Calling `\myShowTree{m}` and `\myShowTreeFinalVersion{m}` in the document environment is of course nonsense, although the arguments are just dummies, the statements should read: `\myShowTree{12,6,17,3,10,15,23,4,7,11,12,16,8}` etc.

Comment: Also, I have made @egreg 's answer to tobi 's question of Feb 5, '16 work. My question is a duplicate and may safely be thrown on the scrap-heap. Thank you.

Comment: If that question solved it for you, you might want to mark your own question as duplicate.